# regex match only if there is one occurence of string and it's the last occurence

Tags: regex

Hopefully the title made sense

My current regex is this `.phone.*.telephoneNumber\/?$`. I'm trying to match json paths and paths would look like this

1. /phone/0/telephoneNumber - should match
2. /phone/0/telephoneNumber/telephoneNumber - should not match

With my current regex this both matches

I need that `.*` 0 or more any character before telephone number because there could be anything after `/phone/..` and i'm trying to look for matches where it ends with `telephoneNumber` only if it's not followed by another `/telephoneNumber`

Comment: It's confusing when you begin your question by presenting your attempt to solve a problem that is not yet known to the reader. It's like beginning a conversation by saying, "I've tried attaching the green wire to the blue wire and the red wire to the black wire, but it's not working. Here is what I'm trying to do:...". I suggest you always begin questions by explaining the problem you are trying to solve, with no reference to what you've tried. Next, if helpful to readers, provide one or more examples, showing the desired result for each. Only then discuss what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> 0 or more any character before the telephone number.

If you meant the count of characters could be 0 or more then use this

```
\/phone\/(?:\w+\/)?telephoneNumber\/?$
```

If you meant that it should be a number greater than 0 then use this

```
\/phone\/\d+\/telephoneNumber\/?$
```

Answer (score 0):

if **telephoneNumber** is a literal string then you can use a negative lookahead to make sure that it is not in between **phone/**  and **/telephoneNumber**.

```
\/phone\/0\/((?!telephoneNumber).)*telephoneNumber$
```

matches `/phone/0/telephoneNumber`
does not match `/phone/0/telephoneNumber/telephoneNumber`

**Warning** this matches `/phone/0/telephonenumber/telephoneNumber` unless we use the option `/i` case insensitive.
The full regex is therefore

```
/\/phone\/0\/((?!telephoneNumber).)*telephoneNumber$/gmi
```

see https://regex101.com/r/1WEF3U/1